# Is Morn ever shown eating or drinking outside of Quark's?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, quark

Besides for special events (Bajoran holidays, etc.), is Morn ever shown eating or drinking outside of Quark's? Say, in the Klingon restaurant, the Replimat, or other places?

There's an episode where he [licks a jumja stick](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/5/51/Morn_isst_einen_Jumja-Stick.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150329125637&path-prefix=de), but is there another example (I'm more interested in an actual "dining" experience)?

Comment: Well, there was that one time he hit Quark with a barstool, ran out of the bar and through the Promenade, screaming "We're all doomed!", then ran into the Bajoran shrine, stark naked, and began crying to the Prophets for protection.

Comment: I'm not even sure Morn is shown eating or drinking *inside* Quark's.  Sure, he sits there and acts like he's *about* to eat or drink, but that's not eating or drinking.

Comment: Great point, Kevin. If it were in my power, I'd promote you to lieutenant.

Answer (score 3):

Morn attended the party in Jadzia's quarters in the episode "You are Cordially Invited". He's even still there in the morning when Worf arrives, and comes stumbling out of the closet with Lieutenant Atoa while holding a margarita glass in one hand.

Comment: I have restored my answer, because your is being upvoted and mine had been downvoted, so I deleted it. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

## He was most likely drinking at Jadzia's bachelorette party

In [DS9: You Are Cordially Invited](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/You_Are_Cordially_Invited_(episode)), we can see Morn getting up in the morning from behind an armchair with a glass in his hand. I believe it is safe to assume that he was drinking that night.

[image: Morn's hangover]

There is also the Jumja stick case, which was brought by the OP and found by Valorum

Comment: It's not shown though.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for but he did drink a lot of liquid latinum in the episode "Who Mourns for Morn" and we see him regurgitate some of it.

Comment: technically he drank it soon after stealing the GPL with the group, when they split up and he ran away